# Neo4j 2.3.0 Browser - node properties popup dialog not showing up

Tags: properties

I am new to Neo4j, everything works fine, but, when the graph is displayed and when I click on a node no popup appears showing the properties.

My install:
Neo4j Community Edition, 2.3.0, Intel Core I7, windows 8, firefox or safari or chrome (and Norton security)
same with Linux Debian 8 same with Windows xp (and ZoneAlarm)

Thanks.
Michel.

Answer (score 0):

You may be familiar with older versions of Neo4j where a pop-up with the properties appears.  In newer versions (starting with 2.2) the properties appear at the bottom of the graph visualization window when you hover over a node.  When you single click on a node those properties stay there (unless you're hovering over another node).  If you don't see all the properties, click on the black disclosure triangle in the lower right of the graph visualization window.

Pro-tip: If you want to change the style of how nodes of a particular label display, click on the label at the top of the graph visualization window and then you'll be able to choose the color and size of the nodes as well as which properties is displayed inside of each node.

Comment: Thanks very much Brian... Exactly what I should have guessed myself ;-)